# WCF JSON - do not return those fields which are null al all

Tags: json, wcf

I have to return trough Json an object like this:

```
User={
    id:4,
    name:'Peter',
    nickname:null
}
```

So my C# object looks like:

```
class User {
    public int Id {get;set;} 
    public string name {get;set;} 
    public string nickname {get;set;} 
}
```

WCF automaticly translated the C# obkect to the Json above. But If nickname is null, how can I tell WCF not to return it at all, so the JSOn returned would be

```
User={
    id:4,
    name:'Peter'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know WCF uses the DataContractJsonSerializer for serializing objects to JSON. Usually you have there a class annotated with `DataMember` attributes which again have an `EmitDefaultValue` property (default is `true`; see [docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue.aspx))

> Gets or sets a value that specifies whether to serialize the default
>   value for a field or property being serialized.

So it might work if you do something like the following:

```
[DataContract]
class User {

    [DataMember]
    public int Id {get;set;} 

    [DataMember]
    public string name {get;set;} 

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public string nickname {get;set;} 
}
```

Note, I didn't try this by myself. You'd have to check, but it sounds like it could work.